# how load multiple xml file with statment?

Tags: actionscript-3

i want load 3 xml file, when i click first button, xml 1 load ect. this my code

```
function action(e:Event):void {

var xmlLoadPelajaran:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
switch(e.target.name){
    case stringPelajaran [0]:
        xmlLoadPelajaran.load( new URLRequest( urlFolder + "pelajaranKelas1.xml"));
    break;

    case stringPelajaran[1]:
        xmlLoadPelajaran.load( new URLRequest( urlFolder + "pelajaranKelas2.xml" [1]));
    break;

    case stringPelajaran[2]:
        xmlLoadPelajaran.load( new URLRequest( urlFolder + "pelajaranKelas3.xml" [2]));
    break;
}
xmlLoadPelajaran.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, selesai );
```

}

Comment: Well what's the problem?

Comment: You are calling URLRequest incorrectly - it only requires one argument, why are you sending a string for URL then an array (as these are not separated by commas, this would be a syntax error anyway)?